# Transaction has been reverted by the EVM - No Reason Error - UniswapV3

Tags: transactions, uniswap, uniswapv3, failed-transaction

There are a lot of failed transactions on Uniswap Router V3 like that one:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa9ead0fd5802ebbbd72280dfdf7b755ab954afdfbb00f8693e07148ee183c93a/advanced

It fail without error, all have the same behavior in "Internal Txns" tab, can someone help to understand why these transactions are failing and how to prevent?

[image]

Comment: The gas used is around 99%, which points to the gas limit being too low.

Comment: now i am also thinking it is a fee problem